# How compare UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want cache `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` and return cached renderer if i used it before for that `CGRect` and `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat`

I tried:

1. `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat == UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat`
2. `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.isEqual(UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat)`

but both ways always return `false`

Any ideas or workaround ?